# bounty question disappeared

Tags: support, questions, bounties

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162157/lost-richfaces-skin-when-rendering-through-richpanel-and-a4jinclude) disappeared as soon as I'd placed a bounty on it.  Where has it gone?  It's not even listed in my list of questions on my SO profile.

Comment: it is listed on your profile: http://stackoverflow.com/users/259453/mark-lewis

Comment: it has now appeared in my list - although it definitely wasn't there once i'd placed a bounty on it.  i obviously wanted it available to general view in the featured list.  see also below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is currently listed on the [3rd page of featured questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=3&sort=featured).  From the initial featured questions page you must click on the **Browse the complete list** link and browse the additional pages of questions to find it, but its there.

Comment: Likewise, it is on page 2 of the user's profile (since this sorts by votes by default).

Comment: ah - i was looking for a page crumb and it looked like the posts were on one page.  cheers